# When should I return TRUE and when FALSE on DialogProc

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

I had another SO question and people there helped me solve an issue. I don't understand what DialogProc is supposed to return on each `case`. What does DialogProc returning TRUE mean? How does it compare to FALSE? What's the difference?

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nc-winuser-dlgproc) states that there is no return value.

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        wchar_t c0_txt[] = L"Title";

        LVCOLUMNW col{};
        col.mask = LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVIF_IMAGE;
        col.cx = 60;
        col.pszText = c0_txt;

        ListView_InsertColumn(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_LIST1), 0, &col);

        return TRUE;
    }
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return FALSE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDOK:
        case IDCANCEL:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        const int width = LOWORD(lParam);
        const int height = HIWORD(lParam);

        // IDC_LIST1 will occupy the entire client area of its parent.
        // Adjust as needed.
        MoveWindow(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_LIST1),
            0, 0, width, height, TRUE);

        return TRUE;
    }
    default:
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int nShowCmd
)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    HWND hWnd = CreateDialogParamW(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDD_MAIN), nullptr, &DialogProc, 0);

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBoxW(nullptr, L"Dialog Creation Failed!", L"Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nShowCmd);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessageW(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: The page you linked to states `Typically, the dialog box procedure should return TRUE if it processed the message, and FALSE if it did not. If the dialog box procedure returns FALSE, the dialog manager performs the default dialog operation in response to the message.` What about that is unclear to you?

Comment: @AlanBirtles, oh I missed that one for some reason. However, I still don't get it. What's the difference between a processed and not processed message?

Comment: If you return `FALSE` then in most cases the message gets passed to `DefDlgProc` to handle (which might then pass it on to `DefWindowProc`). If you want to provide your own behaviour for certain messages rather than accept the default behaviour, return `TRUE` to tell the dialog manager that you handled the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is that you have a `default: return FALSE;`, while each `case:` returns `TRUE`. But Windows doesn't read your code. Windows doesn't even require your code to be written in C++, and other languages may implement the same idea in other ways. That's why the documentation describes the behavior, not how you should implement it.

Comment: Ah, so my `WM_COMMAND` and `WM_NCDESTROY` should also return TRUE?

Comment: @nop: The `WM_COMMAND` is a bit weird. It has three `break`s, including an `break` after the `switch`. This last `break` breaks out of the `switch (msg)`, and then you do `return TRUE;`. Thus, `WM_COMMAND` is the only way that you can reach that final `return TRUE`. But it seems you **don't** handle most `WM_COMMAND`s, and therefore should return `FALSE` in those cases.

Comment: Oh got it, if I handle all ways, I return TRUE. If I don't I return FALSE.

Comment: @nop: That still sounds somewhat wrong. " If I handle all ways" - no. The only question is: "did I handle this specific message?". That **will** depend on `msg`, but it can **also** depend on `wParam` and `lParam`. Again, Windows doesn't look at your source code, it just gives you a `msg, wParam, lParam` and looks at the result.